# When making an AlertDialog the variables don't appear defined

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm having problems with my first app (learning android studio as i go), I'm trying to insert a Alert Dialog whenever the user clicks on the list item to make sure he wants to delete the item. However, I can't get it working, here's the code if you need more just ask for it. Oh I'm portugues btw, so don't get confused by the variables.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private EditText tarefasET;
private Button btn;
private ListView tarefasList;

private ArrayList<String> tarefas;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tarefasET = findViewById(R.id.todoEditText);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    tarefasList = findViewById(R.id.lvTarefas);

    tarefas = FileHelper.lerData(this);

    adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tarefas);
    tarefasList.setAdapter(adapt);

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    tarefasList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.addBtn:
            String newTarefa = tarefasET.getText().toString();
            adapt.add(newTarefa);
            tarefasET.setText("");

            FileHelper.escreve(tarefas, this);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Tarefa Adicionada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int posicao, long id) {
    AlertDialog confirmDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Confirmação")
            .setMessage("De certeza que pretende eliminar a tarefa?")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    tarefas.remove(posicao);
                    adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    FileHelper.escreve(tarefas, this);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Tarefa Eliminada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();

}
```

}

What can i do? The app is suposed to be a to-do list, and i can already add and delete files. But i wanted to make a confirmation dialog when the user decides to delete the item he has to-do. But the code gives me the folowing error when i try and lauch the app to the emulator.

[the error i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Wv2.jpg)

Comment: It's not quite clear what the problem is. Are you getting a compilation error? Is it not working as expected at runtime? Please [edit] your question to explain exactly what issues you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to reference your activity class via `this` variable. Use class name before `this` keyword to get outer reference:

```
    FileHelper.escreve(tarefas, MainActivity.this);
```

Why the problem appears?

Because of the [variable scope](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope). The same rules apply to `this` keyword. Imagine it as a default final variable defined for you by the language.

In your particular case, `this` keyword references the instance of `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` you created. The same issue will appear in case any of the `MainActivity` class level variables names will clash with a variable name of method level variable defined in `onClick`:

```
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        ArrayList<String> tarefas = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<String> outerTarefas = MainActivity.this.tarefas; // not just tarefas or this.tarefas
    }
}
```